# How to insert image into cell , instead of "over the cell" in excel using spring boot

Tags: java, spring

this is the method to insert image into the excel, I want it to be inserted into the cell . But it is getting inserted into excel worksheet as overlay

private  void exportToExcel(List <List> data, Path filePath) throws IOException {
// create workbook and sheet
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("User Data");

```
        // create header row
        XSSFRow headerRow = sheet.createRow(0);
        XSSFCellStyle headerStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
        XSSFFont headerFont = workbook.createFont();
        headerFont.setBold(true);
        headerStyle.setFont(headerFont);
        String[] headers = {"Sr.No.", "Date", "CRN", "Courier Shipment Id", "Name", "Address1", "Address2", "Address3", "Address4", "Address5", "Pin Code", "Mob. No.", "AWB No.", "Courier service provider name","CRN BARCODE","CRN BarcodeLINK"}; //Column Headers for Excel Sheet Generation
        for (int i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
            XSSFCell cell = headerRow.createCell(i);
            cell.setCellValue(headers[i]);
            cell.setCellStyle(headerStyle);
        }
        XSSFCellStyle contentStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
            int j = 0;
            XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(i + 1);
            for ( j=0; j < (headers.length)-2; j++) {
                XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(j);
                cell.setCellValue(data.get(i).get(j));
                cell.setCellStyle(contentStyle);
            }
            XSSFCell cell =row.createCell(j);
            String imagePath = data.get(i).get(2)+".png"; // replace with the actual path to the image file
            Path processedPath = Paths.get(PROCESSED_DIR);
            Path barCodeImage= processedPath.resolve(imagePath);
            String pathvariable=barCodeImage.toString();
            
            
            
            InputStream barcodeInputStream = new FileInputStream(pathvariable);
            
            int pictureIdx = workbook.addPicture(barcodeInputStream, Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG);
            barcodeInputStream.close();
            CreationHelper helper = workbook.getCreationHelper();
            Drawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
            ClientAnchor anchor = helper.createClientAnchor();
            anchor.setCol1(headers.length - 2);
            anchor.setRow1(i + 1);
            anchor.setCol2(headers.length-1 );
            anchor.setRow2(i + 2);
            anchor.setDx1(0);
            anchor.setDy1(0);
            
            anchor.setAnchorType(ClientAnchor.AnchorType.MOVE_AND_RESIZE);
            anchor.setAnchorType(ClientAnchor.AnchorType.DONT_MOVE_AND_RESIZE);
            Picture picture = drawing.createPicture(anchor, pictureIdx);
            
            picture.resize(0.9);
            
            
            cell.setCellStyle(contentStyle);
            
            XSSFCell celllink =row.createCell(j+1);
            Hyperlink hyperlink = helper.createHyperlink(HyperlinkType.DOCUMENT);
            hyperlink.setAddress("" + (i + 1) + "," + (headers.length - 1));
            celllink.setHyperlink(hyperlink);
            celllink.setCellValue("CRN BARCODE");
            
            
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
            sheet.autoSizeColumn(i);
        }
        
        // save workbook to file
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(filePath.toFile());
        workbook.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.close();
        workbook.close();
    }
```

I am trying to insert image into the cell . But with this code i am only able to insert image "over the cell" not "in the cell" using spring boot

Comment: If you want to put the image to place it in a cell , then while edit or do some operation the image will be gone, seems you approch is good , but I want to know why you want to do so